# Having quite different results in matrix multiplication with numpy and cudamat

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to do the same matrix multiplication using numpy and cudamat.

The results are quite different.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- cuda 7.0-28
- nvidia 346.46
- numpy 1.9.2
- Python 2.7.10
- Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)
- cudamat (latest release at Jun th 26th, 2015)
- Nvidia 750Ti

And this is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cudamat as cm
cm.init()

...

def distance(self, X):
      gpu_W = cm.CUDAMatrix(self.W)
      gpu_X = cm.CUDAMatrix(X)
      gpu_X2 = cm.pow(gpu_X, 2).sum(axis=1)
      gpu_W2 = cm.pow(gpu_W, 2).sum(axis=1)
      prodWX = cm.dot(gpu_W, gpu_X.T)
      prodWX = prodWX.mult((-2))

      W=self.W
      prodWXgpu=prodWX.asarray()
      prodWXcpu=-2*np.dot(W, X.T)

cm.shutdown()
```

The results are:

[image]

Both are bidimensional arrays.  Their shapes are:

W (14,2)
X (10000, 2)

It implies two multiplication and an addition per each cell.
So it shouldn't be due to the cummulative error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: cm.pow was modifying the matrixes received as parameter.

To solve it, I changed:

```
gpu_X2 = cm.pow(gpu_X, 2).sum(axis=1)
gpu_W2 = cm.pow(gpu_W, 2).sum(axis=1)
```

by:

```
gpu_X2 = cm.empty (X.shape)
gpu_W2 = cm.empty (W.shape)

cm.pow(gpu_X, 2, target=gpu_X2)
gpu_X2 = gpu_X2.sum(axis=1)
cm.pow(gpu_W, 2, target=gpu_W2)
gpu_W2 = gpu_W2.sum(axis=1)
```